# style name of a real cartoon image

Tags: brush, style

Does the image below have a style name? I want to see more images like this to be more familiar and inspire to make such these photos by adobe illustrator, Where can I find them?

[image]

Comment: Please read our [requirements for style-identification questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2931/52050) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Ive done. Is it okay now?

Comment: @user287001 plz write more clear. I didn't understand.

Comment: There is no specific name for this. If you are looking for other examples on google try searching terms like "combining photo and illustration" or "photo and illustration collage", etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's useless to search an established term for this combination of photo, drawing and software effects. There are so many ways to combine photos with other images (drawings, paintings, sculpts). Many drawn parts have strong black outlines (=strokes). Stars and white dots are as well painted with scattering brush, symbol sprayer or by inserting them manually one by one.

I guess Illustrator would be more useful to make this composition because handling the mass of same looking symbols is there more flexible. The same is true for arranging shapes to regular looking patterns and inserting consistent colors and strokes.

Compositions starting from a photo have been made as long as photos have been easily available. This can be made as well with traditional tools outside the computer, only the drawing skills must be more finely tuned. That's because traditional tools often do not give a second try. That makes experimenting difficult, one must be able to imagine the wanted result more accurately. But the ability to imagine something not before seen is as important to a computer artist. Stacking colors, strokes and effects in a random way very rarely generates something interesting - at least, if one hasn't collected a loyal audience which accepts anything with the right signature.

Answer (score 0):

The technique was used in the movie, *A Scanner Darkly*. Try using "A Scanner Darkly style image" as search term for an image search, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: It's not the same. The movie has posterized colors and edge detection filterings at least for the major characters  of the scene . Questioner's image has redrawn clothes and many drawn add-ons, but the human is untouched.

Comment: But the principal is the same. It's a faux rotoscope effect. You can choose which parts of the image you wish to "cartoonify," it doesn't have to be the characters. In any event, the search term I suggested also pulls up a fair number of tutorials which might include a wider variety of images. I was simply trying to give him a starting point..

Comment: Erm, _principle_.

Comment: @pbr in this image it is clear is made by hand. thank toy anyway

Comment: In *film* it is called Rotoscoping. It's not the same thing in static images.

Comment: @Scott  "FAUX rotoscope effect." Here's a tutorial using the term in the way I was using it, _Combining Reality With A Rotoscope-Style Painting In Photoshop_ [link] (https://www.photoshopessentials.com/photo-effects/rotoscope/). I think we're beating this to death. I surrender.